# Enable exec and shell exec in php?

Tags: php

I need to enable two functions and enable file_get_contents on my cPanel server. The problem is I cannot seem to enable these functions at all.

I do not have access to my php.ini unless I SSH into it. The specific issue is that because I need to turn the functions on, I need to edit the disable functions line. The code according to my phpinfo is the following:

```
disable_functions = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system
```

When I really need it to say

```
disable_functions = no value
```

In phpinfo, I see the filepath to the php.ini file. I also heard you can use /usr/local/lib/php.ini. Whenever I SSH into both files, it reads the following:

```
disable_functions =
```

I have tried adding a set of quotation marks and it doesn't work. I have contacted GoDaddy numerous times and they can't help. I went into SSH to work on the files and nothing changed. I've created a .user.ini file which didn't work either.

Where is my phpinfo getting it's source from and what do I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: check loaded configuration file in your `phpinfo();` output

Comment: Can you check if `allow_url_fopen` disabled or not? if [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is disabled, there is no way you can enable `file_get_contents`. Only the root user can edit the php.ini file which would control that setting.

You can request again to your host enable it, or see if [cURL](http://php.net/curl) is enabled on the shared server.

Comment: allow_url_fopen is enabled and the output of the php.ini file's disable_functions in blank